AppCheck Token is refreshed on every getToken()
I have the following Flutter code:
final token = await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken(false);

On every call I get a NEW token, which is slow ~300ms.
My setup:

iOS using AppleProvider.appAttest
Token TTL 1h
Physical Device (but Debug Mode)
FirebaseAppCheck.instance.setTokenAutoRefreshEnabled(true)

Is this working as intended?
